# Ask for Frank Wilczek's notes on entropy and entanglement

Tags: specific-reference, entanglement-entropy

I know that I am not asking a question on physics. My question is just about learning physics. I am studying entanglement entropy and find [some lecture notes by Frank Wilczek](http://frankwilczek.com/2014/evaluatingGeoEntropy01.pdf)

But I can only find the first and second part of this series of notes on entanglement entropy, I can not find the third part of his notes.

I also find the first part of [another series of lecture notes on entropy and entanglent](http://frankwilczek.com/2014/entropyEntanglement01.pdf), but can not find the second and third parts.

Can some one give my links or send me copies?